# query error on content provider user dictionary

Tags: android

```
   String[] mProjection =
   {
    // UserDictionary.Words._ID,    // Contract class constant for the _ID column name
   UserDictionary.Words.WORD,   // Contract class constant for the word column name
   UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE  // Contract class constant for the locale column name
  };

   searchvalue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    mSelectionClause = UserDictionary.Words.WORD + " LIKE ?";
    mSelectionArgs[0] = searchvalue.getText().toString();

   Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
   UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,  
   mProjection,                       
   mSelectionClause,                  
   mSelectionArgs,                    
   null);
```

Any ideas why I am getting bind or column index out of range on this query?

Comment: You should always post you LogCat errors if your app crashes...

Comment: how do you initialize `mSelectionArgs`? Try `String[] mSelectionArgs = { searchvalue.getText().toString() };`, instead of set the value of  `mSelectionArgs[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error bind or column index out of range was due to the fact that I was not including Primary key field (UserDictionary.Words._ID) in the projection field.